# Opening shapefiles without prj-file (one of Gauss–Krüger CS) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, germany

I'm trying to open a shapefile in Gauss–Krüger coordinate system, which comes without any `.prj`-files, in QGIS. These files are not really up to date but they're the only data i can get.

Is it possible to project them on any world map in the right position by using the `"OpenLayersPlugin"`?

The other part of the data is more updatet so its CRS is ETRS 89 / UTM 32N. Is there a way to project both on the same map for the same time?

When I insert the Gauss–Krüger data into QGIS, it says that the CRS of the Gauss–Krüger data is undefined and preset to EPSG:4326. What does that mean?

So I need a way to show both, old and new data, beside each other on the right position in the map (Google Satellite from OpenLayersPlugin).

Comment: You must know the correct coordinate system, QGIS can't guess it for you. If you did not get .prj file that defines the projection read the documentation about your data set or ask from the data provider.

Comment: The CRS of the shapefile must be UTM 32 because its location is in Germany... But there is no differnce, even when I reproject the shapefile to the right CRS

Comment: There are several Gauss-Krüger zones in Germany, see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gau%C3%9F-Kr%C3%BCger-Koordinatensystem#Gebrauch_in_Deutschland. You have to choose the right one to assign it to your layer. Once it is placed in the right spot, you can reproject it to UTM.

Answer (score 2):

As DirkB already pointed out, you need to use the `Assign projection` tool from the Processing Toolbox. Do this for both of your shapefiles, then they should display correctly. knutella already hinted at the possibility to change your map's projection, so adjust this to fit your needs.

Aside this, I personally recommend to scratch `OpenLayersPlugin` and use `QuickMapServices` instead, with which I had fewer issues when it came to projections and printing maps. You can also enable additional providers (per default, many of the good ones are disabled) by going to:

```
Web --> QuickMapServices --> Settings
```

then click on the `More Services` tab and click `Get contributed pack`. Save, exit, have fun with it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You got many different tools to accomplish this task.

You should find a way with the tools from processing if you search for "proj"[image]

- If you dont have a .prj file with your shapefile then you're using
  **Assign projection**
- If you've got a .prj file then better use **Reproject layer**

In both cases you need to know what your needed CRS / EPSG code must be.

Comment: `Reproject layer` would not place the shapes to another place on the Earth, while `Assign projection` does. So I suggest to assign.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to reproject your whole project with the QGIS-button in the bottom-right:
[image]

or just reproject your shapefile-layer to the crs used by gmaps wms.

This done via right-click on the shape-layer -> "Properties..." -> "Source"-tab:

[image]

Comment: Changing the **project** CRS does not alter the location of the shapefile's data. Changing the layers CRS is not **reprojecting**, and you still have to know what CRS your data is in. Not necessarily that of the wms.